# ¿cómo puedo poner botones en la barra de tareas para formularios que no son el formulario principal?

Tags: windows, delphi

¿Cómo se puede lograr que un formulario secundario aparezca en la barra de tareas de Windows en Delphi?

He visto varias aplicaciones dónde cuándo se abre una nueva ventana, se crea un botón nuevo para dicha ventana secundaria en la barra de tareas, sin crear un nuevo proceso. Por defecto, en una aplicación escrita en Delphi se pueden crear y mostrar formularios secundarios, pero solamente aparece un botón en la barra de tareas de Windows, no se visualizan separadas al hacer  <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>.

¿cómo puedo cambiar este comportamiento?

Mi código actual luce como este:

```
procedure Form1ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.Show;
end;
```

He estado pensando llamar a `CreateWindowEx`, pero mi solución ideal debiera ser más simple que tener que llamar directamente a la API de Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede lograr lo que quieres sobreescribiendo el método `CreateParams` del/los formulario/s que quieres que tengan su propio botón en la barra de tareas. Con la solución propuesta, estos formularios también se minimizarán de manera independiente, así:

```
interface

type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
  ...
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams) ; override;
  ...

implementation

procedure TMyForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams) ;
begin
  inherited;
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
  Params.WndParent := 0;
end;
```

De hecho, podrás encontrar una explicación más amplia (en Inglés) en el artículo [Minimize child forms independent of the main form](https://web.archive.org/web/20170809065156/http://delphi.about.com:80/od/formsdialogs/a/child_forms.htm) en delphi.about.com

Ten en cuenta que el artículo referenciado en about.com es incorrecto en cuanto a establecer como WndParent del formulario al escritorio. En el blog "The Old New Thing" encontramos una grandiosa explicación (en Inglés) de [por que es incorrecto hacer el escritorio el padre de las ventanas de tu aplicación](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/2004/02/24).

Con información de [How can I get taskbar buttons for forms that aren't the main form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493591/how-can-i-get-taskbar-buttons-for-forms-that-arent-the-main-form)